# ¿Como dividir o separar una consulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server

creo una tabla Virtual(Ficticia)

```
SELECT TOP 1 ItemID
INTO #Temp
FROM PS_GameData.dbo.CharItems
WHERE ItemID = 1001
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES((SELECT ItemID FROM #Temp));
SELECT ItemID
FROM #Temp
DROP Table #Temp
```

¿Como separo esta consulta que va en una misma hoja sql?
para que no me diga en la consulta .sql existe la tabla #temp 
IMPORTANTE son 65000 Consultas necesito hacerlas todas en un mismo archivo de extencion .SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1 ItemID
INTO #Temp
FROM PS_GameData.dbo.CharItems
WHERE ItemID = 1002
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES((SELECT ItemID FROM #Temp));
SELECT ItemID
FROM #Temp
DROP Table #Temp
```

OK favor intentar esto en una Misma Hoja de SQL y correjir error sin sacar la consulta de SQL

```
       SELECT TOP 1 ItemID
        INTO #Temp
        FROM PS_GameData.dbo.CharItems
        WHERE ItemID = 1001
        INSERT INTO #temp VALUES((SELECT ItemID FROM #Temp));
        SELECT ItemID
        FROM #Temp
        DROP Table #Temp;
-- Termina Consulta
       SELECT TOP 1 ItemID
        INTO #Temp
        FROM PS_GameData.dbo.CharItems
        WHERE ItemID = 1002
        INSERT INTO #temp VALUES((SELECT ItemID FROM #Temp));
        SELECT ItemID
        FROM #Temp
        DROP Table #Temp;
```

Error:

**Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
There is already an object named '#Temp' in the database.**

PD: no cuesta mucho ejecutar dicha consulta

Answer (score 1):

He modificado la consulta. Le faltó fue esto:

```
   SELECT TOP 1 ItemID
    INTO #Temp
    FROM PS_GameData.dbo.CharItems
    WHERE ItemID = 1001
    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES((SELECT ItemID FROM #Temp));
    SELECT ItemID
    FROM #Temp
    DROP Table #Temp; -- que hace semi-separar pero no completa 


   GO -- aqui termina de Separar limpiando creo la cache

-- Termina Consulta
       SELECT TOP 1 ItemID
        INTO #Temp
        FROM PS_GameData.dbo.CharItems
        WHERE ItemID = 1002
        INSERT INTO #temp VALUES((SELECT ItemID FROM #Temp));
        SELECT ItemID
        FROM #Temp
        DROP Table #Temp;
```